# JAVA When do the values of variables get pushed into the stack?

Tags: java, stack

When do the values of the variables get pushed into the stack? It's compile-time or it's in run-time?

Comment: Hint: The stack doesn't exist at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The value are pushed into the stack only at the runtime in java.At compile time only the .class files are generated